# OpenCV C++ Mat == operator

Tags: c++, opencv, mat

I'm using open CV in C++ , but i need some help at this example:

`getContours((mask == 0), contours, hierarchy)`

where this function just call
`findContours` function from Open CV. I don't understand what really does `mask == 0` as a parameter. `mask` is defined as a `Mat` data type. It`s a binary image black & white.

Comment: I understand , it`s like an invert ,than you very much

Answer (score 2):

The `==` is a [Matrix Expression](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html?highlight=mat_#matrix-expressions)  that produces a binary matrix (of type `CV_8UC1`).

`mask == 0` creates a binary mask where pixels are set to `255` if it was `0` in `mask`, or `0` otherwise.

If `mask` is binary, you're basically inverting it, same as `~mask`.